# Is Smoking Cigars and Pipes the Same as Cigarettes?

Tags: smoking

My brother-in-law smokes pipes and cigars. He says they're not bad like cigarettes but I thought smoking anything is bad. Is it true that pipes and cigars aren't detrimental to your health like cigarettes?

Comment: Your brother-in-law is wrong. Searching [Google](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=Is+Smoking+Cigars+and+Pipes+the+Same+as+Cigarettes%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=FH1NWoalE6nu8we6sqyYAw) for the exact text of your title will bring up many, many articles indicating that nicotine is every bit as bad for you, whichever way you take it.

Comment: Drawing smoke containing hundreds of damaging chemicals into your mouth, throat, nasal passages, and lungs is detrimental to your health. Period. Are they the same as smoking cigarettes? Who cares? They're both damaging to your health and they both lead to cancer.